# Testing for convergence, not sure which test to use: $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

> I am asked to test 
>   $$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} $$
>   for convergence.

So here is my thought process:
I look at the convergence of the absolute value and recognize that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$ is a divergent $p$-series, which I believe means the series is at least not absolutely convergent.
But then I'm not sure what to do... Do I use the Alternating series test? I don't think I can because the absolute value of the series is not decreasing, so do I use the ratio test?

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: The absolute value of the series is decreasing.

Comment: Yes, use the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). In fact, that series is CC

Comment: Before we do anything, why do you think that the absolute value of the series is not decreasing?  Show us that and we can help you, because I believe your problem lies there.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Math.SE. Please see the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help putting equations in your post.

Answer (score 5):

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Then $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$. With this, it is clear that $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for all  $n$, which shows that $(a_n)$ is decreasing where all $a_n$ are positive. Note that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0.$$ Hence, using the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), the given series is convergent.

---

**Note:** If we let $u_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ then  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\bigg|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg| \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{n}}{(-1)^n}\bigg|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}}=1$$ and this tells us that the **Ratio Test fails.**